# Last Modified or IfModifiedSince Android SQL HTTP

Tags: android, mysql, http

I have an App that Retrieves and Posts Data to an SQL Server.

My situation is this: It is currently set to download the JSON Data from the server every time the App is opened. The Server (1000's of rows and 15+ columns)
data is only updated every couple of days or a few times a week. It seems inefficient and silly to update every time the app is opened if the data hasn't changed.

I only want this data to update if the data has been updated.

I'm trying to use this:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Long lastModified = urlConnection.getLastModified();
```

It seems to be returning 0, which means the value is not set?

**Do I need to set something on my server to allow it to respond to a getLastModified Request?**

note: I am able to see the last updated statistic on phpmyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

you could do other things instead :

- you could add new table or new field that have date for the last modified date , and let the app get this info and compare it to your local date , and then decide eather you update or not .
- you could deal with meta data but idk if your sql server do that .
- or you can set service on the android device that update the data base every 2 days always but this way is not so efficient .

Comment: Your first suggestion was my second plan if I could not get this to function properly. Thanks for the suggestions!